# Perl script for moving files

Tags: perl

I have developed a Perl script for data movement from one folder to another. I have one folder in D drive (`D:\projectx\MUX4TO1_TB`). Inside that folder, I have to create a new folder named `newfolder`. Then I want to search for `.ps` files inside `MUX4TO1_TB`, and if any are found, I want to move them to `newfolder`.

The code I have developed is 70% working, but data movement is not happening from `MUX4TO1_TB` to `newfolder`. Please help me to complete it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use File::Copy 'move';

my $srcdir = "d:\\projectx\\MUX4TO1_TB";
mkdir("D:\\projectx\\MUX4TO1_TB/Newfolder") || die "Unable to create directory <$!>\n";
my $dest = "D:\\projectx\\MUX4TO1_TB\\Newfolder";
opendir(DIR, $srcdir) or die "Can't open $srcdir: $!";
$filterstring = ".ps";

foreach my $filename (readdir(DIR)) {
    if ($filename =~ m/$filterstring/) {                          
        $cfile = $srcdir . $filename;
        print "\n moving $cfile from $srcdir to $dest \n";
        move($cfile, $dest) or die "The move operation failed: $!";                             
    }
}

closedir(DIR);
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide a valid path of the final target

```
$cfile= $srcdir. '\\' . $filename;
```

You missed `\\` backslashes while assigning a new value to `$cfile`.

Full code:

```
use warnings;
use File::Copy 'move';
my $srcdir= "d:\\projectx\\MUX4TO1_TB";
mkdir("D:\\projectx\\MUX4TO1_TB/Newfolder") || die "Unable to create    directory <$!>\n";
my $dest = "D:\\projectx\\MUX4TO1_TB\\Newfolder";
opendir(DIR, $srcdir) or die "Can't open $srcdir: $!";
$filterstring=".ps";
foreach my $filename (readdir(DIR))
{
    if ($filename =~ m/$filterstring/) {                          
        $cfile= $srcdir. '\\' . $filename; ## You missed '\\';
        print "\n moving $cfile from $srcdir  to $dest \n";
        move($cfile,$dest)or die "The move operation failed: $!";                             
    }
}
closedir(DIR);
```

Comment: if i have multiple folder in same directory for example   "MUX4TO1_TB1" ,"MUX4TO1_TB2" all the folder contain same .ps files . In this case how to  update the code to meet the requirement . can u plz help on this. I just tried if statement but its showing syntax error

Comment: @RAHUL That's a different question, and it requires a different answer. You should ask a new question.